# Save files to a new folder with python

Tags: python, directory, text-files, ssml

This code saves text files from a data frame of sentences, then saves each one as a ssml file.

How can I get the sentences to be saved in a new folder?

```
max = len(sentences) 
for i in range(0,max):
    txt = sentences[i]
    new_txt = starter + txt + ender   
    print(new_txt)
    num = num + 1 
    with open("text" + str(num) + ".ssml", 'w+') as f:
        f.writelines(new_txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the start:

```
import os

folder_name = 'my_folder'
os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)
```

Then change:

```
with open("text" + str(num) + ".ssml", 'w+') as f:
```

to:

```
with open(f'{folder_name}\\text{num}.ssml', 'w+') as f:
```